# Add new columns automatically in forms & reports

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table [tblProject] with fields like [Task] & [Start Date] and I have Task1, Task2 & Task3 at the moment. At the same time a query outputs a tabular view with columns as [Start Date], [Task1], [Task2] & [Task3], 
a form in datasheet view and a report use such query as the source.

I would like to know if it is possible to setup the query / form / report to display automatically possible new columns like [Task4]...[TaskN] in case of more new tasks added in [tblProject]. How can I work it out if it involves VBA or simply just multiple queries would do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

1) Design the form with the maximum number of Task columns you will need and set them to `Visible = FALSE`. Then at runtime you will make them visible as needed.

2) Add the controls as needed using the `CreateControl` method.

In either event you will need to determine how many task columns you have. I suggest you loop through the field names to determine the number of tasks to show.